# pty module - 'os.read' of master is reading what was just written to master

Tags: python, python-3.x, pty

UPDATE: This was solved. pty initializes the pseudo-devices in canonical mode, echo must be disabled. See [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46670094/3785172).

The following unittest passes:

```py
def test_pty(self):
  mfd, sfd = pty.openpty()
  pty.tty.B38400
  devName = os.ttyname(sfd)

  ser = serial.Serial(devName, baudrate=38400, timeout=1)

  test_str = b'testing'
  os.write(mfd, test_str)

  time.sleep(1)
  self.assertEqual(ser.readline(), test_str)
```

Showing that bytes written to the master pseudo-device are read on the slave pseudo-device.

However, if I switch the order of two of the statements:

```py
def test_pty(self):
  mfd, sfd = pty.openpty()
  pty.tty.B38400
  devName = os.ttyname(sfd)

  test_str = b'testing'
  os.write(mfd, test_str) # Write first

  ser = serial.Serial(devName, baudrate=38400, timeout=1) # Then set up serial

  time.sleep(1)
  self.assertEqual(ser.readline(), test_str)
```

Then it fails. `ser.readline()` reads zero bytes.

I noticed that the following also passes:

```
def test_pty(self):
  mfd, sfd = pty.openpty()
  pty.tty.B38400
  devName = os.ttyname(sfd)

  test_str = b'testing'
  os.write(mfd, test_str) # Write to master

  self.assertTrue(test_str, os.read(mfd, len(test_str)) # Read from master
```

Essentially, if I `os.write` to the master device *before* I set up a serial connection to the slave device, then the bytes are echoed/written (?) on the master pseudo-terminal instead of the slave's.

Please help me understand why this is.

(Python 3.4.8)

EDIT:
replaced `pty` with `pseudo-device`, as `pty` is a pair of devices

Comment: [This reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46670094/3785172) worked for me after I resolved another bug. It appears that the pseudo-devices are created in canonical mode, and that the echo needs to be disabled.